# cannot create the rspec files on windows 'rails app"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm running on windows 7 and I cannot install/create the rspec files and capybara  which is needed to work on the assignment .

If you could finish the simple setup steps listed below  and give me a link to the empty app repository  so I could download to finish the assignment , I will be so gratefull to you .

by the way , I 'm getting the following errors in step 4 if someone could help . I have asked before but no one have answered ;(
[image]
[image]

Steps needed :

1. Create a new Rails application called todolists
2. Add the following specification to your Gemfile

   group :test do

   gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'

   gem 'capybara'

   end
3. Run the bundle command to resolve new gems
4. From the todolists application root directory, initialize the rspec tests using the rails generate

rspec:install command

```
[todolists]$ rails generate rspec:install

create .rspec

create spec

create spec/spec_helper.rb

create spec/rails_helper.rb
```

Add the following line to .rspec to add verbose output to test results.

```
--format documentation
```

5. Download and extract the starter set of bootstrap files.

   1

   |-- Gemfile

   |-- db

   | ‘-- seed.rb

   ‘-- spec

   ‘-- features

   ‘-- module3_action_pack_spec.rb

• overwrite your existing Gemfile with the Gemfile from the bootstrap fileset. They should be nearly identical,

but this is done to make sure the gems and versions you use in your solution can be processed by the

automated Grader when you submit. Any submission should be tested with this version of the file.

• overwrite your existing db/seed.rb file using the seeds.rb provided with the bootstrap fileset. The

bootstrap seeds.rb file contains some test data that will be useful during development and unit tests.

• add the spec/features/module3_action_pack_spec.rb file provided with the bootstrap fileset to your

todolists application. Within your application root directory, you will first need to create a corresponding

spec/features sub-directory to place the module3_action_pack_spec.rb file. This file contains tests that

will help determine whether you have completed the assignment.

6-run rspec

Comment: please remove the `Steps needed` section from the question. Its irrelevant

Comment: but I'm not able to run those steps on windows , i just want the rspec files to work on the assignment

Comment: i have asked before for a solution ,but no one have answered .

Comment: @KarremEmad. Look at my answer and see if it helps. And btw, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to ask a good question. Everyone is busy and you can't ask them to read a very long question. Please remove the `Steps needed`  section if you want to get answers.

Comment: If I could get a solution  , i won't have asked for this . thanks  , Arun . I will remove the whole question  , it seems that no one have an answer ,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that rspec versions > 2.8.0 don't go well with `Windows`. Can you try to install an older version of `rspec-rails`? Include this in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.8'
```

Run `bundle install` and then try

```
rails g rspec:install
```

Comment: yes , I have tried this and it works for running rails generate rspec:install   ,,,,but rspec command don't work because this version  2.8 don't create all necessary as the newer versions do

Comment: @KareemEmad, If you tried that, you should have included that in the question.

Comment: ok, I will re-create it ,just waiting for bundle update to finish

Comment: I couldn't embed images in my post anymore  , so i have upload it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/50u1hbs51bacgu4/55.png)

Comment: @KareemEmad, Find a file which `requires` `rails_helper` and replace it with `spec_helper`. Let me know if this solves the issue

Comment: yes , I found the file  ,but I could find that require statement  ,the error log points to line  54  in the file  which is   return gem_original_require(path)   , i will upload this file for you if you want to look at

Comment: *could  not  find